# Elegant way to .seek on an open file

Tags: python, io

I've come across this issue more than once, when you open a file in python using `with open` while reading it in small bytes, once you've read the bytes if on the next line you read more bytes it starts from where you've left off with the last call. For example:

```
def read_it(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        print f.read(4)
        print f.read(4)
        print f.read(4)
        print f.read(4)


read_it("test.rtf")
#<= {\rt
#<= f1\a
#<= nsi\
#<= ansi
```

The solution for this issue is to add `.seek(0)` after each read to start from the beginning:

```
def read_it(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        print f.read(4)
        f.seek(0)
        print f.read(4)
        f.seek(0)
        print f.read(4)
        f.seek(0)
        print f.read(4)


read_it("test.rtf")
#<= {\rt
#<= {\rt
#<= {\rt
#<= {\rt
```

However, as you see calling `.seek` multiple times is pretty ugly. I'm look for a more elegant way to seek back to 0 after each read. Is this possible?

As mentioned this is python2, here's the same issue in python3:

```
Python 3.8.8 (tags/v3.8.8:024d805, Feb 19 2021, 13:18:16) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("test.rtf", "rb") as f:
...     print(f.read(4))
...     print(f.read(4))
...     print(f.read(4))
...
b'{\\rt'
b'f1\\a'
b'nsi\\'
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you read the first bytes multiple times? And why do you still use the out of date Python 2?

Comment: File header detection mostly @KlausD, the above is just an example since one file can be checked for multiple header types. IE MZ, %PDF, {\RTF, PK, etc

Comment: Still does not make any sense. Except in rare case of a concurrent access this should read the same data four times.

Comment: Assuming I have to use `.seek`, is there an elegant way to do it?

Comment: Additionally, even if you needed different lengths (for example, if you needed one variable to be the start of a header and another to be the whole header), it would make more sense to read all the data and store an index of it.

Comment: Also, this is a problem in both 2 and 3. It's not related to the version its always been there (on windows anyways), see updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly came up with this:

```
class Rewinder:

    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.fd = None
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.fd = open(self.fname)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
        self.fd.close()
        self.fd = None

    def read(self, size=-1):
        try:
            return self.fd.read(size)
        finally:
            self.fd.seek(0)
        

with Rewinder('test.txt') as f:
    print(f.read(4))
    print(f.read(4))
    print(f.read(4))
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think it would make sense to add a parameter `seek` with a default of 0 instead of always being 0, but this seems like what is wanted.